# bit calculation complement of x how it works?

Tags: python, bit

Can someone explain to me why:

```
print(~60) == -61?
```

because 60 is `111100` then reverse is `000011` and it should be 3?

Answer (score -1):

Even assuming you are using one byte - 60 would be `0011 1100`

So ~60 would be `1100 0011`

i.e. -128 + 64 + 2 + 1 = =61